# Differential equation given 2 limits as hints

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

My friend brought a Korean book and has this problem to show me.
The problem goes like this:

Given this function:$$f(x)=(x^2+x+1)(ax+b)$$
Find $f'(3)$ given that:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to1}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=3$$
$$\lim\limits_{x\to2}\frac{x^3-8}{f(x)-f(2)}=1$$

I by far managed to get the derivitive of the function $$\frac{dy}{dx}=3ax^2+2(a+b)x+(a+b)$$
and that$$f'(3)=34a+7b$$
I would need help finding $a$ and $b$.
I'm having difficulty doing the limits bit.

Comment: I think your limits are wrong. Should't it be $x$ instead of $n$?

Comment: Oh yes should be $x$ sorry, my english is not that good

Answer (score 1):

Given this function:$$f(x)=(x^2+x+1)(ax+b)$$
Find f '(3) given that:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to1}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=3$$
$$\lim\limits_{x\to2}\frac{x^3-8}{f(x)-f(2)}=1$$

Using your result for $f'(x)$ as
$$f'(x)=3ax^2+2(a+b)x+(a+b)$$

Now we note that the first limit you wrote down is equal to the derivative in $x=1$. Hence, we conclude: 
$$\lim\limits_{x\to1}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=3=f'(1)$$

For the second limit we have to note that $x^3-8=(x-2)(x^2-2x+4)$. 
$$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{(x-2)(x^2-2x+4)}{f(x)-f(2)}=\lim_{x\to2}\frac{(x-2)}{f(x)-f(2)}\lim_{x\to2}(x^2-2x+4)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to2}\frac{(x-2)}{f(x)-f(2)}\cdot 4=1$$

In the last step I calculated the limit on the right hand side. Now we notice that $\lim_{x\to2}\frac{(x-2)}{f(x)-f(2)}$ is the inverse of your derivative in $x=2$. Hence, we can conclude:

$$f'(2)=4$$

Now plug in these values into your general formula for $f'(x)$. You will get a system of two equations with two unknowns.

$$f'(1)=3=3a\cdot1^2+2(a+b)\cdot1+(a+b)$$
$$f'(2)=4=3a\cdot2^2+2(a+b)\cdot2+(a+b)$$

I leave the rest to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use L'Hospital for the second limit (the first limit is just $f'(1)\,$) together with $f'(x) =3ax^2+2ax+a+2xb+b$ and $p(x)=x^3-8$ to get
$$3 = f'(1) = 6a+3b$$
$$1 = \frac{p'(2)}{f'(2)}=\frac{12}{17a+5b}$$ 
Can you solve the following linear system for $a,b$?
$$6a+3b=3$$
$$17a+5b = 12$$

> $a=1,\,b=-1,\,f'(3)=27$